# can't add Android Material Design Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm trying to follow Google's material design guidelines and therefore I would like to use the new Toolbar instead of the old ActionBar. But how do I set it in my Activity? The MainActivity has two screens that can be swiped left/right.

The setSupportActionBar method is not found and setActionBar requires a different version of the toolbar. Any idea?

```
package com.bla;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.bla.ui.TabsPagerAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        // does not work WTF!
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager_list_views);
        TabsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are extending `FragmentActivity` try to change it to `AppCompatActivity`

Change it as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Don't forget to import

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Read the [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) it might help you to understand why :)

Comment: Thanks, found it. But it's not returning. The method simply does not exist in FragmentActivity

Comment: You should mark as a correct any answer... since you have the correct approach to solve your question :P

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

You should be extending the [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) class, as the [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) class doesn't have the `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)` method. It does however have a `setActionBar(Toolbar)`, but that method expects a non-support-v7 version of the `Toolbar` to be used.